How to draw a rectangle the height of the page
I'm trying to make a resume. I wanted to draw two rectangles, one that is about 1/3 of the width of the page and the other takes up the rest of the width. Then, I want to add all the text in the rectangles. I tried this:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (current page.south west) rectangle (\paperwidth/3,\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I'm just a beginner with Tikz, and I saw that there are a lot of ways to draw rectangles. I don't know if it's better to use \draw or maybe a node, path, fill...
Then I want to use a minipage with the height and the width of the rectangle to center all my text within my rectangles.

You need the the keys remember picture and overlay on your TikZ picture for something like this to work. Section 17.13.2 has examples about current page. You probably want a node with the right dimension (but you don't really need current page when you just make the node/picture the right size. Maybe tcolorbox is better suited for your document, though.

Welcome to tex.sx.  I'd be inclined to try \fbox wrapped around minipages.

@Qrrbrbirlbel There are surely a lot of ways to do it. If you have any examples to give me, please do so. This is what I have done so far: I finally divided the pages into two rectangles. TikZ is so complicated for me; I think I need an overview because I feel like there are a lot of ways to do something.

@barbarabeeton Do you have any example ?

I will try to come up with an example.  But it won't have any color -- I don't have much experience with that.

First, you need to add ++ to your rectangle so that the second point is placed relative to the previous point and not the origin.  Note that the lines draw by tikz are half in and half out on the page edges (default line width is 0.4pt).
This shows how to put a minipage inside a node, or how to effectively create a minipage using the node options.  Note that the total width is the text width plus 2 times inner sep (default 0.333em).  The main difference is the align option.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=0cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}% radnom text
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth/3,\paperheight);
\path (current page.west) ++(\paperwidth/6,0) node[%draw,
  text width={\paperwidth/3 -0.666em},
  minimum height={\paperheight},
  align=justify]
{\lipsum[1]};

%\path (current page.west) ++(\paperwidth/6,0) node[red]{\begin{minipage}[c][\paperheight][c]{\dimexpr\paperwidth/3 -0.666em}
%  \lipsum[1]
%\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}% you will need a \newpage to prevent overlaping this one
\end{document}


I have found this, there is so manny ways to do it i think.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[rectangle,draw, fill=RoyalBlue, RoyalBlue, minimum width = \paperwidth/3 , minimum height=\paperheight,anchor=south west] (r1) at (current page.south west)  {};
\node[rectangle,draw,fill=beige, beige, minimum width = 2*(\paperwidth/3), minimum height=\paperheight,anchor=south west] (r2) at (r1.south east)  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
Maybe i can just use \node and position my text in the rectangle, no need for minipage
